# jQuery extend() in extend()

Tags: jquery, plugins, extend

These are my jQuery plugin parameters so far:

```
function lightbox( options )
{
 // setting default parameters
 var params = $.extend(
 {

    // show/hide & enable/disable options
    keyNav : true,                      // boolean
    objClickNav: false,                 // boolean
    showNav : true,                     // boolean
    showTitle : true,                   // boolean
    showPagination : true,              // boolean
    debugMode : false,                  // boolean
    disableScrolling : true,            // boolean
    fullscreen : false,                 // boolean

    autoScale : true,                   // boolean
    staticHeight: 'auto',               // integer or 'auto'
    staticWidth: 'auto',                // integer or 'auto'

    // content options
    contentType : 'image',              // defines the type of content shown in the lightbox
                                        // options: 'image'
    animationType : 'default',          // defines the type of animation when switching objects
                                        // options: 'default', 'slide'

 }, options);
}
```

I couldn't find an answer anywhere on the internet, so that's why I'm asking it here. I want to have an `extend()` inside the current `extend()`, so I can declare my plugin like this:

```
lightbox({
  keyNav : true,
  showNav : false,
  scale({
    autoScale : false,
    staticHeight : 800,
  })
  content({
    contentType : 'image',
    animationType : 'slide',
  })
});
```

What is the correct way of doing this?

Comment: You should be creating a default setting objects with the same structure as the settings passed in to the plugin, then you can just `$.extend` it. What you have now is a flat object as the default, and then suddenly a nested object is being passed in, you're going to have a lot of trouble iterating and figuring out what goes where, instead of just making them the same structure to begin with.

Comment: Maybe you could explain with an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`$.extend`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/#jQuery-extend-deep-target-object1-objectN) documents a **`deep`** flag. `scale` and `context` would typically be objects, which the deep flag would tell `extend` to clone.

Also note that the first entry should be the object to extend, which you normally **wouldn't** want to be your defaults object. (Although in your case, you're recreating the defaults each time, so that's fine.)

So:

```
var params = $.extend(
    true, // <=== The `deep` flag
    {},   // <=== The new object that will be stored in `params`
    {/*...your big defaults object...*/},
    options
);
```

Simple example:

```js
(function($) {
  var fooDefaults = {
    text: "coolness",
    style: {
      color: "green",
      fontWeight: "bold"
    }
  };
  
  $.fn.foo = function(options) {
    var params = $.extend(true, {}, fooDefaults, options);
    this.data("params", params); // Just so we can look at them
    return this.each(function() {
      $(this).text(params.text).css(params.style);
    });
  };
  
})(jQuery);

var a = $("#a");
var b = $("#b");
a.foo({text: "I'm a"});
b.foo({style: {color: "blue"}});
console.log("a's text: " + a.data("params").text);
console.log("a's color: " + a.data("params").style.color);
console.log("b's text: " + b.data("params").text);
console.log("b's color: " + b.data("params").style.color);
```

```html
<div id="a"></div>
<div id="b"></div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```